# How to resolve Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.mongodb.MongoEntity

Tags: java, mongodb, grails

I am trying a very simple code in grails.

I have added below lines in build.gradle file.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.5"
compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'
```

But when I try to execute the code, it is giving me following error at the line of Database connection:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.mongodb.MongoEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

What is the problem here? Do I need to add another jar in classpath or there is some version problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your gradle file:

```
'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:4.0.7.RELEASE'
```

You can find more information about that class here: http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/5.0.x/mongodb/api/grails/mongodb/MongoEntity.html